Streak for a given endDate SQL (Postgres)
Input data



date
number




2024-11-02
1000


2024-11-03
500


2024-11-05
1000


2024-11-06
1000


2024-11-07
1000


2024-11-08
500


2024-11-14
1000


2024-11-15
1000



for a given date I want to get the streak (dates backward in a row where number is above/equals a certain threshold => in the examples always 1000)
Examples:

date input 2024-11-15 => Result 2
date input
2024-11-14 => Result 1
date input 2024-11-8 => Result 0
date input 2024-11-7 => Result 3
date input
2024-11-5 => Result 1

If I search using a date which doesn't appear in the data (for example, 2014-11-12), I want the result to be 0.
I would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you so much!
I have another example:
Input data



date
number




2024-12-10
1000


2024-12-13
1000


2024-12-14
1000



query for date 2024-12-14 should return 2 (count 14. 13.) There is a gap between 13. and 10. So the 10. should not count.

If the date input is for example 2024-11-12, what result do you want?

@JonasMetzler Since 2024-11-5 should be 1, I'm guessing that 2024-11-12 should give 0.

I was just trying to, in a nice way, say that the answer to your question is in the post

@JonasMetzler sorry not to mention it. 2024-11-12 should return 0. because there is no streak.


Streak CTE will assign a row_number to all the dates where number is >= 1000.
Then streak is SELF JOINED to find the dates which are consecutive and the number of days are counted based on difference of row numbers.

EDIT

since single output is expected, one additional LEFT JOIN is added to return the streak when the date is present, otherwise return 0.

Fiddle
WITH streaks AS (
    SELECT 
        t.date,
        t.number,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.date) AS rn
    FROM test t
    WHERE t.number >= 1000
),
consecutive_dates AS (
    SELECT
        s1.date,
        COUNT(*) AS streak_length
    FROM streaks s1
    LEFT JOIN streaks s2 
        ON s2.rn <= s1.rn AND s2.date = s1.date - INTERVAL '1 day' * (s1.rn - s2.rn)
    GROUP BY s1.date
)
SELECT
    i.date,
    COALESCE(cd.streak_length, 0) AS streak_length
FROM (SELECT '2024-11-13'::DATE AS date) i 
LEFT JOIN consecutive_dates cd ON i.date = cd.date;

Output



date
streak_length




2024-11-13
0



EDIT : DATE contains timestamp, we just use the date portion from the timestamp.
Fiddle
WITH streaks AS (
    SELECT 
        t.date::DATE AS date,  
        t.number,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.date::DATE) AS rn  
    FROM test1 t
    WHERE t.number >= 1000
),
consecutive_dates AS (
    SELECT
        s1.date,
        COUNT(*) AS streak_length
    FROM streaks s1
    LEFT JOIN streaks s2 
        ON s2.rn <= s1.rn 
        AND s2.date = s1.date - INTERVAL '1 day' * (s1.rn - s2.rn)
    GROUP BY s1.date
)
SELECT
    i.date,
    COALESCE(cd.streak_length, 0) AS streak_length
FROM (SELECT '2024-11-15'::DATE AS date) i 
LEFT JOIN consecutive_dates cd ON i.date = cd.date;


I just want to have a single result. so the last streak for a given date

I have edited and added a condition to left join when the date is not present @user1117605

thanks this works great. I just have 1 additional question. would do I have to change if the date column is a timestamp? but still ignoring the Time?

I have Edited the answer if the dates are in timestamp, so we just take the date part from it, I have added the link to fiddle as well where I have tested https://dbfiddle.uk/L0rUvHqr @user1117605

Thank you so much. I works as expected :-)

You are welcome! Glad you found it helpful :)

This is one of cases of gaps and islands.
select date,number
  ,sum(case when number>=1000 then 1 else 0 end)over(partition by grn order by date) result
from(
  select *,sum(case when number<1000 then 1 else 0 end)over(order by date) grn
  from test
)a





date
number
result




2024-11-02
1000
1


2024-11-03
500
0


2024-11-05
1000
1


2024-11-06
1000
2


2024-11-07
1000
3


2024-11-08
500
0


2024-11-14
1000
1


2024-11-15
1000
2



If you want to get a result for a specific (given) date, you can do this
select coalesce(max(date),cast('2024-11-04' as date)) date,count(*) cnt
  from test
 where date <= '2024-11-04'
   and date > (select max(date) from test
                where date <= '2024-11-04' and number < 1000)




date
cnt




2024-11-04
0



When no row in table for given date, query returns cnt=0.
For  existing date
select coalesce(max(date),cast('2024-11-07' as date)) date,count(*) 
  from test
 where date <= '2024-11-07'
   and date > (select max(date) from test
                where date <= '2024-11-07' and number < 1000)

Output is



date
cnt




2024-11-07
3



fiddle
UPDATE1
Case when num<1000 is gap and missing date is also gap
Test data



date
number




2024-11-02
1000


2024-11-03
500


2024-11-05
1000


2024-11-06
1000


2024-11-07
1000


2024-11-08
500


2024-11-14
1000


2024-11-15
1000


2024-12-10
1000


2024-12-13
1000


2024-12-14
1000



Query for given date (paramDate)
with params as(select cast('2024-12-16' as date) paramDate)
select paramDate date,number, coalesce(result,0)result
from params p
left join  (
  select date,number
    ,sum(case when number>=1000 then 1 else 0 end)over(partition by grn order by date) result
    ,grn
  from(
    select *
     ,sum(case when number<1000 then 1 
            when (date-interval '1 day')<>prevDate then 1
          else 0 end)
         over(order by date) grn
    from(
       select *,lag(date,1,date)over(order by date) prevDate
       from test
      )a
    )b
)c on p.paramDate=c.date




date
number
result




2024-12-12
null
0



select date,number
  ,sum(case when number>=1000 then 1 else 0 end)over(partition by grn order by date) result
  ,grn
from(
select *
  ,sum(case when number<1000 then 1 
            when (date-interval '1 day')<>prevDate then 1
       else 0 end)
    over(order by date) grn
from(
  select *,lag(date,1,date)over(order by date) prevDate
  from test
  )a
)b





date
number
result
grn




2024-11-02
1000
1
1


2024-11-03
500
0
2


2024-11-05
1000
1
3


2024-11-06
1000
2
3


2024-11-07
1000
3
3


2024-11-08
500
0
4


2024-11-14
1000
1
5


2024-11-15
1000
2
5


2024-12-10
1000
1
6


2024-12-13
1000
1
7


2024-12-14
1000
2
7



fiddle

hi @ValNik, but your second query ignores date gaps? For me it's important that a missing date entry is like number 0 .Thanks for your answer.

Second query works for dates, existing in table and for dates, missing in table.

but it does not work for me. I have another example: input date is 2024-12-14 (data: (2024-12-14, 1000), (2024-12-13, 1000) (2024-12-10, 1000). With your query the response is 3 but actually it should be just 2. (only 14. and 13. count)

thanks for your update. Unfortunately I get for all dates result 0. I tried 2014-12-14, 2024-12-13 or 2024-12-10. Always the same. What do I wrong?

oops, posted the preliminary version. Answer updated. See corrected query. Please, check booth '2014-12-14' and '2020-12-14' with test data. Should be 0 and 2.

Thank you for your effort. Your solution works as expected. The query of @samhita is a little bit more cost efficient regarding the execution plan. That's why I gave her the green hook.

With classical gaps and islands technique:
select date, number, 
    case when grp is not null then row_number() 
         over(partition by grp order by date) 
    else 0 end as streak_length
from (
    select date, number, case when grpstart is not null then 
          sum(grpstart) over(order by date) end as grp
    from (
        select 
            date, number, 
            case when number >= 1000 then
                case when (lag(number) over(order by date) < 1000) then 1 else 0 end 
            end as grpstart
        from test
    )
)
order by date


This finds the number of rows that have a date less than or equal to a certain date and have dates later than the previous day where the number was below the threshold
select count(*) 
  from table
 where date <= '2024-11-15'
   and date > (select max(date) from table
                where date <= '2024-11-15' and number < 1000)


Most simple is to use recursivity :
WITH RECURSIVE streak AS (
    SELECT 
        d.date,
        d.number,
        1 AS streak_counter
    FROM data d
    WHERE d.date = '2024-11-07'.  --> Your date here

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        d.date,
        d.number,
        streak.streak_counter + 1
    FROM data d
    INNER JOIN streak ON d.date = streak.date - INTERVAL '1 day'
    WHERE d.number >= 1000
)
SELECT MAX(streak_counter) FROM streak;

